# If the beneficiary of a Will is implicated or convicted of the deceased murder, does the Will still stand?

Tags: law, estate-planning, will

Honestly, I don't consider this to be a valid concern to my own financial planning, but having had the thought, I just wondered whether there are automatic provisions in law to nullify or remove murderous beneficiaries, or if one would have to add specific exemption clauses.

Suggestions for the wording of such a clause would also be appreciated

Comment: Are you going to murder or fear being murdered :) ?

Comment: Dumbcoder: I'd be more worried if the heading read, "Do I still get the dosh if I torch the gaff with everyone in it?" :P

Comment: +1 for helping me learn a new phrase "slayer rules". Now, to find a way to use it in ordinary conversation tomorrow!

Comment: @DumbCoder - neither, the question just occurred to me!

Comment: @duffbeer703 I heard the phrase "Slayer rules!" quite a bit in high school in the 80s. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to look.

Murderers, beneficiaries, common law, and statutes:

http://www.drbilllong.com/Insurance/Murder.html

Note that slayer rules are common law (inheritance) and require a lesser degree of proof to deny the slayer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slayer_rule

Re the ruling of a clause - as it's written into common law you don't need to do anything: http://www.deathandtaxesblog.com/2005/04/more_on_slayer_statutes.html

Bottom line: In all likelihood, the killer gets nothing. Although, depending upon the US state and how good their attorney is - you just never know.

Answer (score 5):

It appears there is 'protection' under UK law, but I've been unable to find any further information.

From a [BBC News Article](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/uk/3197018.stm) (2003)..

> The law says their son could not receive anything because he had carried out [their] murder.

And another from the [Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-423512/Judge-attacks-law-makes-murder-likely.html) (2006)..

> Currently people convicted of murder or manslaughter cannot inherit from their victims

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the same as life insurance.  If you kill the person / have them killed, you don't get the insurance payout / benefits from the will.